# Error while building MFC 4.1 project in MFC 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I downloaded a project which was originally developed in MFC 4.1. I'm trying to build that project in MFC 6.0. When I opened it using `Open WorkSpace`, and build it, then following error came.

> Link : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "mfc42ud.lib"

On internet I found a solution to fix this error by ignoring this library from Project settings. I did that and then another error on similar lines appeared for `mfcs42ud.lib` file. And I fixed that too.

[image]

When I added both the .lib files to ignore list, and build it, then I'm getting 901 errors like below....

> --------------------Configuration: doodads - Win32 Unicode Debug-------------------- Linking... doodads.obj : 
> error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE ADDRESS.OBJ : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE expose.obj :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE
>   progress.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __afxForceEXCLUDE MaskDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE SETKEY.OBJ : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE SPINNER.OBJ : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE stats.obj : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE ANIME.OBJ :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE STDAFX.OBJ
>   : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE
>   MAINFRM.OBJ : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __afxForceEXCLUDE DODADDOC.OBJ : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE DoDadvw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __afxForceEXCLUDE doodads.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX ADDRESS.OBJ : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX expose.obj :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX
>   progress.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __afxForceSTDAFX MaskDlg.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX SETKEY.OBJ : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX SPINNER.OBJ : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX stats.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX ANIME.OBJ : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX STDAFX.OBJ : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX MAINFRM.OBJ :
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX
>   DODADDOC.OBJ : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   __afxForceSTDAFX DoDadvw.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __afxForceSTDAFX

Here is the code file for your reference.

**Add.h**

```
// ADD.H - Header file for your Internet Server
//    add Extension

#include "resource.h"

class CAddExtension : public CHttpServer
{
public:
    CAddExtension();
    ~CAddExtension();

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
        //    DO NOT EDIT what you see in these blocks of generated code !
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CAddExtension)
    public:
    virtual BOOL GetExtensionVersion(HSE_VERSION_INFO* pVer);
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

    // TODO: Add handlers for your commands here.
    // For example:

    void Default(CHttpServerContext* pCtxt,
                            LPCTSTR pstrOp1, LPCTSTR pstrOp2);

    DECLARE_PARSE_MAP()

    //{{AFX_MSG(CAddExtension)
    //}}AFX_MSG
};
```

**Add.cpp**

```
// ADD.CPP - Implementation file for your Internet Server
//    add Extension

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "add.h"

#include <stdio.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// command-parsing map

BEGIN_PARSE_MAP(CAddExtension, CHttpServer)
    // TODO: insert your ON_PARSE_COMMAND() and 
    // ON_PARSE_COMMAND_PARAMS() here to hook up your commands.
    // For example:

    ON_PARSE_COMMAND(Default, CAddExtension, ITS_PSTR ITS_PSTR)
    ON_PARSE_COMMAND_PARAMS("opone=~ optwo=~")
    DEFAULT_PARSE_COMMAND(Default, CAddExtension)
END_PARSE_MAP(CAddExtension)


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The one and only CAddExtension object

CAddExtension theExtension;


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CAddExtension implementation

CAddExtension::CAddExtension()
{
}

CAddExtension::~CAddExtension()
{
}

BOOL CAddExtension::GetExtensionVersion(HSE_VERSION_INFO* pVer)
{
    // Call default implementation for initialization
    CHttpServer::GetExtensionVersion(pVer);

    // Load description string
    TCHAR sz[HSE_MAX_EXT_DLL_NAME_LEN+1];
    ISAPIVERIFY(::LoadString(AfxGetResourceHandle(),
            IDS_SERVER, sz, HSE_MAX_EXT_DLL_NAME_LEN));
    _tcscpy(pVer->lpszExtensionDesc, sz);
    return TRUE;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CAddExtension command handlers

void CAddExtension::Default(CHttpServerContext* pCtxt,
                            LPCTSTR pstrOp1, LPCTSTR pstrOp2)
{
    StartContent(pCtxt);
    WriteTitle(pCtxt);

    int nOp1;
    int nOp2;

    if (*pstrOp1 != '~' && *pstrOp2 != '~')
    {
        nOp1 = atoi(pstrOp1);
        nOp2 = atoi(pstrOp2);

        char sz[1024];

        sprintf(sz, "The result is: %d\n", nOp1 + nOp2);
        *pCtxt << sz;
    }
    else
    {
    *pCtxt << "<FORM ACTION=\"http://mooseboy/add.dll\" METHOD=\"GET\">";
    *pCtxt << "Enter the first number: <INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"opone\" VALUE=\"0\" SIZE=10><p>";
    *pCtxt << "Enter the second number: <INPUT TYPE=\"text\" NAME=\"optwo\" VALUE=\"0\" SIZE=10><p>";
    *pCtxt << "<p> <INPUT TYPE = \"SUBMIT\" VALUE=\"Add it up\">";
    *pCtxt << "</FORM>";
    }

    EndContent(pCtxt);
}

// Do not edit the following lines, which are needed by ClassWizard.
#if 0
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAddExtension, CHttpServer)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CAddExtension)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
#endif  // 0



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// If your extension will not use MFC, you'll need this code to make
// sure the extension objects can find the resource handle for the
// module.  If you convert your extension to not be dependent on MFC,
// remove the comments arounn the following AfxGetResourceHandle()
// and DllMain() functions, as well as the g_hInstance global.

static HINSTANCE g_hInstance;

HINSTANCE AFXISAPI AfxGetResourceHandle()
{
    return g_hInstance;
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst, ULONG ulReason,
                    LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (ulReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        g_hInstance = hInst;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Just for information, I've marked Microsoft Foundation Classes to Use MFC in a shared DLL under General tab. Please help, TIA.

Comment: Well you *did* remove the linker libraries that contains those functions, so of course you would get undefined references when linking. Instead of just removing a couple of libraries, you could instead tell the linker to link with the *correct* libraries.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What are the correct libraries that I need to add, because these two are not available in the project that I downloaded, and I have very minimal knowledge of MFC.. Could you please guide? This is MFC 6. for your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MFC 6.0` uses `MFC42*.LIB` library files (strange but true). So it seems you link with the correct filenames.

If you get these error messages when you link your project, I guess that either your project file has something wrong, or `Visual C++ 6` is not correctly installed. The solution is not to remove these libraries, but to find out why Visual C++ doesn't find them.

Your project is compiling in `unicode-debug` configuration. Have you installed the unicode libraries when you have installed `Visual C++`? Maybe this is an `opt-in` install option (not sure). Can you build your project using another configuration, like release-unicode? Or Debug?

What can help you is to create a new empty Visual C++/MFC project `(File/New Project/C++/MFC/MFC Application)`, so will get a valid MFC project configuration. Be sure to choose Unicode configuration, because this is the configuration you want to use.

Comment: I have compiled many projects in VC 6 recently. So VC is installed correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it is installed with unicode libraries?

Comment: How can i check that?

Comment: If Unicode MFC libraries are installed, then then the "new MFC project" wizard let you choose if you want to use unicode or not... You should create a new MFC project, and compare what you get with your project.

Comment: I'm happy I helped. Were the unicode libraries missing in your installation? Or in your project?